# LINQ to XML nested elements query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following Questions.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Questions>
  <Question>
    <Subject>ADO.NET</Subject>
    <Text>Which class should you use to manage multiple tables and relationships among them?</Text>
    <Answers>
      <Answer>DataRow</Answer>
      <Answer>DataView</Answer>
      <Answer>DataTable</Answer>
      <Answer>DataSet</Answer>
    </Answers>
  </Question>
</Questions>
```

which I want to parse. Below are my classes and my query.

```
public class Question
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Answer
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    static void readQuestions()
    {
        var questions = from question in XDocument.Load("Questions.xml").Descendants("Questions").Elements("Question")
                        select new Question
                        {
                            Subject = (string)question.Element("Subject"),
                            Text = (string)question.Element("Text"),
                            Answers = new List<Answer>(
                                from answers in question.Elements("Answers").Elements("Answer")
                                select new Answer
                                {
                                    Text = (string)answers.Element("Answer")
                                })
                        };

        foreach (var question in questions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}\n Text: {1}", question.Subject, question.Text);
            foreach (var answer in question.Answers)
                Console.WriteLine("Answer: {0}", answer.Text);
        }
    }
```

The problem is it prints no Text for Answers. I searched for different nested linq to xml query examples but I can't find what's wrong with mine. Many thanks.

Comment: this is not Linq to SQL

Comment: Sorry. I meant XML. I changed the title and the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change this:

```
XDocument.Load("Questions.xml").Descendants("Questions").Elements("Question")
```

To:

```
XDocument.Load("Questions.xml").Descendants("Question")
```

Or:

```
XDocument.Load("Questions.xml").Root.Elements("Question")
```

Also change your answers query :

```
from answers in question.Element("Answers").Elements("Answer")
select new Answer
        {
              Text = (string)answers
        })
```

Comment: Oh, I was asking for `.Element("Answer")` twice.. That's it. Thanks.